# Can I bundle a complete jdk with my install4j installation?

Tags: install4j

My application needs to do some compilation as part of the install process (I know this is bad form, but there it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compiling, I would simply add lib/tools.jar from the JDK to the distribution tree and add it to the classpath of the launcher. Then you can programatically compile classes.

A more lightweight solution would be to use [janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home).

Comment: We need to install a glassfish 3.1.2.2 alongside our application and it required a full jdk instead of a jre. So will it be possible to bundle a jdk the same way as an jre?

Comment: The JRE bundling in install4j does not handle JDKs. I would check which parts of the JDK are actually required and add them separately. Mostly it's tools.jar.